# Give Border To Texture - SetPixel

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, textures, border

I'm trying to dynamically add a border to a texture of mine. So far, I have a border at the top, and at the bottom. But struggling to get a left and right border. This is what I have so far:

```
var i = image;
var pixels : Color[] = i.GetPixels(0, 0, i.width, i.height, 0); 
var br : int = 1;

for(var p = 0; p < pixels.Length; p++){

    var b : int = 30;

    //Bottom
    if(p < i.width * b)
        pixels[p] = new Color(1,0,0,1);

    //Top
    if(p > (i.height * i.width) - (i.width * b))
        pixels[p] = new Color(1,0,0,1);


    //int when a new row of pixels has began
    if(p > i.width * br)
        br++;

}
```

The pixels are read from bottom left, to top right. I just can't seem to get my head around the maths.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to get x position of a pixel is to use modular operator (%), which returns the remainder.

Here is a code calculating the x position and setting the border based on that:

```
// Left
if(p % i.width < b)
    pixels[p] = new Color(1,0,0,1);

// right
if(p % i.width > i.width - b)
    pixels[p] = new Color(1,0,0,1);
```

Comment: Thank you, now how would I add the border pixel size (b)?

Comment: Also, this doesn't actually do the trick. I end up with a weird reversed triangle effect going on.

Comment: I don't know if its my 'if(p > i.width * br)  br++;' that is causing it.

Comment: Sorry, my typo. The `br` should have been the width of the border. In your case `b`. I edited the answer correspondingly.